# Error: "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" with selenuim

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I want to crawl fully rendered web pages of google playstore search result.

The fully rendered pages have all searched items while the not-rendered pages only have 20 items. (Please see https://play.google.com/store/search?q=best&c=apps&hl=en)

I tried to crawl the pages with selenium, but got the error message below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "play_test_2.py", line 25, in test_play_test2
driver.find_element_by_id("show-more-button").click()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 65, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 385, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///var/folders/8_/n90htn1d0_j4h7l9yt04chl80000gn/T/tmpErWdUz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8959:5)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///var/folders/8_/n90htn1d0_j4h7l9yt04chl80000gn/T/tmpErWdUz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11618:1)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/8_/n90htn1d0_j4h7l9yt04chl80000gn/T/tmpErWdUz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:11)
at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify          (file:///var/folders/8_/n90htn1d0_j4h7l9yt04chl80000gn/T/tmpErWdUz/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:548:5)
```

The bellow code is made by Selenuim IDE.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class PlayTest2(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://play.google.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_play_test2(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/store/search?q=best&c=apps")
        driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfb").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("show-more-button").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("show-more-button").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException, e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I think that the error is occurred because the google store search result page has the "show more" button which is shown up when it meets some specific condition such as scroll down and up then scroll down again.

How can I solve this problem and crawl the google search results pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test_play_test2 calls

> driver.find_element_by_id("show-more-button").click()

**twice**.
 
I suppose that after the first click selenium can't find the same element and failed.
Just remove the one latest line from this method.

**UPDATE:** You absolutely right, the problem that the button is appears only after the page scrolling. Therefore we have to scroll the window.
The following javascript command is helpful

> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");

One command is not enough we have do it several times:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++ ){
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");
    try{
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5/*sec*/))
                        .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        break;
    }
    catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e){
    }
}
if(element.isDisplayed()){
    element.click();
}
```

Sorry I used the Java code for this example, but I hope this will let you the idea.

Comment: I already tried it but it did not work. Moreover, "Show-more" buttons are shown up several times in the web pages.